# how to pass data from single activity to multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my application there is an activity which is having multiple fragments and activity having a spinner when the change operation occurs on spinner then all fragment should change the value, suppose

Activity temp --> fragment A --> fragment B --> fragment C

i can pass data from activity to fragment A -->B-->C using intent but if current fragment is C and the value changes from spinner then fragment C should have latest value and when i press back button then flow is

fragment C --> fragment B --> Fragment A should have latest values,
so how to maintain multiple fragment data passing from single activity

Acivity temp.java

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator {
        void passDataToFragment(String data);
    }

private class onItemSelect implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

             if (f instanceof FragmentA) {

                fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(data[position]);
            }

        }
}
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements temp.FragmentCommunicator {

@Override
    public void passDataToFragment(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        ((temp) context).fragmentCommunicator = this;
       }
}
```

Comment: Look at the EventBus library. Probability useful

Comment: How about using Android new LIVEDATA library (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Interface we can achieve it. Simply we can call it as Data change listener.

Just follow my code to know how it works.

**1.TempActivity.java**

```
public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public List<FragmentCommunicator> fragmentCommunicators = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);

    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"Value One", "Value Two", "Value Three"}));
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

           for (FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator : fragmentCommunicators) {
               fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

       }
   });

   ViewPager viewPager1 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager1);
   FragmentAdapter adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "FirstFragment");
   adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "SecondFragment");
   adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "ThirdFragment");
   viewPager1.setAdapter(adapter);

   viewPager1.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {

           for (FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator : fragmentCommunicators) {
               fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

       }
   });
 }
}
```

**2.activity_temp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**3.FragmentCommunicator.java**

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator {
    void passDataToFragment(String data); 
}
```

**4.FragmentAdapter.java**

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}
```

**5.FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator {
private TextView textView1;
public FirstFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (getActivity() instanceof TempActivity) {
        ((TempActivity) getActivity()).fragmentCommunicators.add(this);
    }
    return view;
}
@Override
public void passDataToFragment(String data) {
    textView1.setText(data);
}
}
```

**6.fragment_first.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**7.Follow same steps for remaining fragments.**

> Create new fragment.
>   Implement FragmentCommunicator interface.
>   Add implemented interface in Activity’s interface list.

**8.Build and run you application. We achieved.**

You can grab my example project [here](https://github.com/Divakar-Murugesh/Examples).

Happy coding…

Comment: Great solution, in my case only works with only fragment i don´t think in use an arrayList, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use LocalBroardCast or eventBus, both is same:
[Evenbus example](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/)

Comment: if i unregister EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this) in onStop then how FragmentB will get data ? if current Fragment is FragmentC and change operation performed in FragmentC then OnBackPress FragmentB resumes, how FragmentB will get data?

Comment: you have 2 option here. If you init fragment by viewpager, use mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3). It means 1 time you will keep 3 fragment, no fragment has been destroy. Second choice, use sticky event bus, it will receive data when it register again.

Answer (score 0):

/**Try to implement the below code Snippet**/

Make a Public String or any type of Method in your Activity atatched to Fragments 
    Inside your Activity:

```
String name = "Jack";

public String getname()
{
    return name;
}
```

Inside your Fragment:

```
Activity mactivity;
MainActivity main_activity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mactivity = getActivity();

    main_activity = (MainActivity) mactivity;

    String name = main_activity.getname();
}
```

That's all same this for all the fragments..Using this you can transfer data form Single Activity to all Multiple Attached Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Observer pattern. I do this for multiple fragments of each tab. All fragments implement an interface with `sendData(String data)` method and MainActivity has a addListener method that adds these interfaces to list object. All fragments use`(MainActivity)activity.addListener(this);` to register itself as an observer.

If an event triggers sending data, using foreach loop in MainActivity send data to send all registered listeners, in this case fragments.

Like all registers i register in onResume and remove listeners(empty list) onPause methods.

Comment: if i remove listeners in onPause method then how it will get data if i'm in fragment C, and on pressing back how fragment B will get data? if i register it in onResume method, but the change operation performed when i'm in Fragment C

Comment: It depends on your needs when to unregister or remove listeners. You can do in onStop(),  onDestryoy(). The point is to implement interface by fragments and use a method in MainActivity to add this interfaces to a list and update interfaces inside the list when one or multiple fragment needs data, use if statement to check fragment meets update conditions, if so send data, else skip that fragment on the list and check for others. It's very simple if you don't want to use an external library.

Comment: By the way onResume() and onPause() are methods of MainActivity not fragments. You unRegister all listeners if they are not already unregistered. You can unregister a fragment in life cycle of a fragment. Also you can unregister all listeners from MainActivity when you are done or you app is not visible(onPause() invoked).

Concept is simple, but when to register or unregister is your choice. It's multiple callbacks or Observer Design Pattern.

Comment: can you post the code of mainActivity addListener method ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

Create a new interface to provide the data needed to the fragments. 
for example:

```
public interface MyDataInterface {
    Data getDate();
}
```

Implement the interface in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyDataInterface {

    // ...

    @Override
    public Data getDate() {
        return dataForFragments;
    }

}
```

Now when your Fragment is attached to the Activity (it's context),
Check if the context is implementing your interface and then use it to pull data from the Activity.

```
public class MyFargment extends Fragment {

private Data mData;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof MyDataInterface) {
        MyDataInterface myDataInterface = (MyDataInterface) context;
        mData = myDataInterface.getDate();
    }
}
```

}

And if you need the data inside your Fragment `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getActivity() instanceof MyDataInterface) {
            MyDataInterface myDataInterface = (MyDataInterface) getActivity();
            mData = myDataInterface.getDate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: should i have to call mData = myDataInterface.getDate() in onResume method also? when pressing back and fragment resumes..

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you need the data inside onResume() check my updated answer.